# RPi 3 no WiFi problem

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, wifi

Last week I've bought used Raspberry Pi 3 and at the beginning everything worked just fine (WiFi especially). Yesterday I took the board out of its small case in order to measure it (I like to model electronic devices in CAD software in my spare time).

I was particularly interested in tiny and shiny rectangle, which as appeared later is a WiFi Broadcom chip:

[image]

After re-assigning everything my WiFi stopped working (Bluetooth operates just fine).

Measuring tool is made from metal, I was doing everything wearing anti-static gloves, however my assumption is that I somehow managed to zap the chip.

I've already made clean installation of Raspbian with no positive results ("No wireless interfaces found"). Are there other possibilities for this problem? How to determine if Broadcom chip is dead or not? I would be grateful for any advice.

Comment: Ive had this issue too and I fixed with sudo service.dhcpd.start

Comment: Have you checked the system logs and output of ```dmesg``` to confirm that the drivers load correctly? Does the interface show up in ```ip link```? If so, it's also worth ensuring that the antenna, located on the other side of the board at next to the screw mounting hole, is intact. The antenna is easy to knock off during handling.

Comment: This happened to me as well. Now, my wifi works intemittently. Sometimes it works, but mostly doesn't. I noticed that grounding the RPi's electronics components (to discharge any static charge) makes the WiFi works sometimes. Not sure though. I also look forward to an answer.